# Memory allocation

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory

How could we decide over how much memory will be good enough for a sql server 2012 standard edition instance having only 1 DB of around 250GB and it's very busy database through out the day, having high number of INSERTs/UPDATEs/DELETEs compared to SELECTs. Also lots of work done in Temptables by almost more than 1000 stored procedures everyday.

Thanks!

Comment: Single database: 100 tables in it, 1000 SP, 350 indexes collectively, various concurrent queries keep running all day long. Avg utilization of CPU is around 45% in a day.

Comment: Most of the time, Compilations/sec is more than 10% of BatchRequest/sec

Comment: Please don't leave important information in comments, which are ephemeral. Add it to your question instead.